# Reading first name for Samples surname in Virginia Tax records of 1806?

Tags: palaeography, 1800s-decade, virginia, taxation-records

In the [Virginia Tax records for Rockingham County in 1806](http://www.binnsgenealogy.com/MembersOnlyArea/pdfs/Rockingham/1806PersonalA/12.pdf), I see the following name written:

[image]

I read the last name as Samples, but the first name I can't figure out.  As best as I can read, it says Bethuel, but I've never heard of that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is again [in 1809](http://www.binnsgenealogy.com/MembersOnlyArea/pdfs/Rockingham/1809PersonalB/13.pdf):

[image]

And [in 1810](http://www.binnsgenealogy.com/MembersOnlyArea/pdfs/Rockingham/1810PersonalA/11.pdf):

[image]

[In 1811](http://www.binnsgenealogy.com/MembersOnlyArea/pdfs/Rockingham/1811PersonalB/10.pdf):

[image]

So it appears that Bethuel is correct.

Bethuel is an [Aramean name from the bible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bethuel).